# How get db name in Kohana 3.2?

Tags: orm, kohana-3.2

how can I get currently used database name in Kohana 3.2?

I've got app(store) with multiple db's and I need to debug whole app if it's working properly.

Kind regards 
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you debug Database::$instances or Database::$instances you'll see all instances and the protected property _current_databases, maybe this helps

```
Database::$instances;
Database_MySQL::$instances;
```

If this doesn't work, you chould execute a query directly to the DB with the MySQL command

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution worked for me:

`Kohana::config('database')`

Answer (score 0):

just in case, someone is still looking:

```
Kohana::$config->load('database')->get('default')['connection']['database'];
```